# problem with the install ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wubi

I need some help to Install ubuntu (I had tried to install 18.04.2& 19.04 & 14.04.6) on my laptop (asus model N752VX original windows 10 home from asus ). I have already asked for help from Ubuntu Linux (GR Greece Greek) but no one can help me . I tried to install it ,with usb or CD or (wubi..... .exe + the ubuntu file) but every time I have some errors (frozen at the ubuntu logo when I restart my laptop or black screen ). ( I have all ready disabled the secure boot control)(and create second hard disk 50GB) Thanks for your time.

Comment: Forget wubi, it's no longer supported.  Nvidia video may be a problem, try the "nomodeset" word added to the grub line (edit with e" starting with "linux" at the "quiet splash" words.